# Write a type-safe function that takes an arbitrary object and generates a CSV string

Tags: typescript

So I'm trying to write a function in TypeScript that takes an arbitrary PDO (defined as an `interface`) and outputs a CSV string (yes, I know that I can probably find libraries to do this, but the ones I have found don't really meet my needs, and I enjoy writing stuff like this)

In order to type the input parameter I started off by creating a mapped type, like so:

```js
interface ArbitraryObjectType {
   [key: string]: unknown
}
```

However when I tried to use this as with the input parameter, the function wouldn't accept my PDO (this is a minimal example, not my real code, so the names are obviously made up):

```js
interface ArbitraryObjectType {
   [key: string]: unknown
}


const generateCsvFromDomainPdo = (thing: ArbitraryObjectType): string => {
   // No code yet, but will eventually output a CSV string
};

interface DomainPdo {
   foo: string;
}

const bar: DomainPdo = {
   foo: "baz"
};

generateCsvFromDomainPdo(bar); /* Error: Argument of type 'DomainPdo' is not assignable to parameter 
                                         of type 'ArbitraryObjectType' */
```

Now it strikes me that the *most* typesafe thing I could probably do would be to type the argument as `unknown`, which would force the function code itself to do some custom type checking (custom type guards etc) before actually doing anything with it.

But I was wondering if there is a middle ground (perhaps using some kind of generic function trickery) that will allow me to pass in an `interface` object (like my `DomainPdo` above) which would then inside the function provide me with a parameter  that:

- could be passed into `Object.keys(...)` and
- could be indexed using the results returned by the same call to `Object.keys(...)`

Comment: You did not share ArbitraryObjectPdo

Comment: @captain-yossarian sorry. Typo - that was mean to be `ArbitraryObjectType`. I've updated the question :)

Comment: Which value types are you expect in `[key: string]: unknown` instead of unknown? All possible? I mean, arrays, symbols, functions, or only serializable?

Comment: I think `unknown` is a reasonable type for the *values* - I'm happy to do type checking there. I'm asking how I can do this without passing the *whole thing* in as `unknown`.

Comment: So, what type are you expect as a result of `Object.keys(thing)` and what are you expect as a return type of function?

Comment: @BenWainwright I think my attempted answer was actually wrong, so I've deleted it

Comment: @captain-yossarian I don’t understand how either of those questions are relevant. The return type of the function has no impact on the type of the parameters or how they are used inside the function, and `Object.keys(...)` can only return a `string[]` because that’s how it is typed.

Comment: @BenWainwright I asked, because I did not know whar are you expecting. If you think my questions are irrelevant, you can ignore them. I'm ok with it

Comment: @BenWainwright you can use `Object.keys(thing) as Array<keyof  DomainPdo>` for typing them